# Plot a multi-variable equation in (discontinuous) regions

Tags: matlab, plotting, octave

The goal is to display the relation between K and E in the following equation:

$$\cos(K) = 5 \text{sinc}( 5.12\sqrt{E} ) - \cos(5.12\sqrt{E} )$$

The intended result is:

[image]

However, using the following code:

```
k = linspace(0, 3*pi, 99);  % 0 < k < 3pi , crystal momentum.
E = linspace(0.1,  3.5, 99);% Energy.
[X, Y] = meshgrid(k, E);

P = 5;                      % 2mU_0b/hbar^2.
Z = cos(X)  - ( P * sinc( 5.12 * sqrt(Y) ) )  - cos( 5.12 * sqrt(Y) );

contour(X, Y, Z);

xlabel('k')
ylabel('E(k)')
legend('cos(K) - P * sin(E) - cos(E)')
title('Dispersion relation for periodic potential in extended zone.')
```

what I currently get unfortunately bears no resemblance at all:

[image]

I just don't see how to separate the graph into three (discontinuous) regions, $K = [0, \pi], [\pi, 2\pi], [2\pi, 3\pi]$, and what value of $E$ should be used for each of these regions.

How to plot the equation the same way as in the first graph?

---

The first plot is from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20624/plotting-extended-zone-scheme), where they do some modular arithmetic trick by adding $i*floor(k ./ \pi)$ on the l.h.s. and $i*floor(5.12*\sqrt{E} ./ \pi)$ on the r.h.s. There is something similar [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/147149/plotting-extended-zone-scheme-plot-3pi-to-3pi?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: I tried to find the solution using bisection and am now convinced that the plot and the closed-form dispersion relation do not correspond to each other.  Highlight the zero level-set in your contour plot and you'll see why, e.g., v = [0,0]; contour(X,Y,Z,v).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you originally wrote that your equation is $\cos(K)=5 \text{ sinc}(5.12\sqrt{E})- \cos(5.12\sqrt{E})$, but you clearly meant $\cos(K)=5 \text{ sinc}(5.12\sqrt{E}) + \cos(5.12\sqrt{E})$

Second, the $\text{sinc}()$ function has differing conventions. [The other question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20624/plotting-extended-zone-scheme) is based on Mathematica, which uses the [convention](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sinc.html) $\text{sinc}(x) \equiv \frac{\sin x}{x}$, while Matlab/Octave use the [convention](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/sinc.html) $\text{sinc}(x) \equiv \frac{\sin (\pi x)}{\pi x}$. (To be precise of course we need to separately define $\text{sinc}(0)\equiv 1$.) This is why your first contour plot shows "no resemblance at all".

Compensating for these differing conventions and altering your code slightly so that it only shows the contours for Z=0 (as suggested in a comment by Biswajit Banerjee) yields

```
k = linspace(0, 3*pi, 99);  % 0 < k < 3pi , crystal momentum.
E = linspace(0.1,  3.5, 99);% Energy.
[X, Y] = meshgrid(k, E);

P = 5;                      % 2mU_0b/hbar^2.
Z = cos(X)  - ( P * pi * sinc( 5.12 * sqrt(Y)/pi ) )  - cos( 5.12 * sqrt(Y) );
contour(X, Y, Z,[0,0],'linewidth',2,'linecolor','k');
for i=1:3
  line(i*[pi,pi],[0,3.5],'color','k','linestyle','--')
end

xlabel('k')
ylabel('E(k)')
legend('cos(K) - P * sin(E) - cos(E)')
title('Dispersion relation for periodic potential in extended zone.')
```

which produces the plot

[image: contour plot]

The best way I could come up with to isolate sections of these curves is to simply run `contour` for the separate regions and plot them together. The following code accomplishes this and generalizes it to `N` sections.

```
P = 5;                      % 2mU_0b/hbar^2.
a=5.12;
N=3;

hold on;


for i=1:N
    k = linspace((i-1)*pi, i*pi, 1000);  % 0 < k < 3pi , crystal momentum.
    E = linspace(((i-1)*pi/a)^2,  (i*pi/a)^2, 1000);% Energy.
    [X, Y] = meshgrid(k, E);

    Z = cos(X)  - ( P * pi * sinc( a * sqrt(Y)/pi ) )  - cos( a * sqrt(Y) );
    contour(X, Y, Z,[0;0],'linewidth',2,'linecolor','k');

    line(i*[pi,pi],[0,(N*pi/a)^2+0.2],'color','k','linestyle','--')
end

xlabel('k')
xlim([0,N*pi+0.2])
ylim([0,(N*pi/a)^2+0.2])
ylabel('E(k)')
```

[image: contour plot sectioned]

Answer (score 0):

Here is something near to the intended goal:

[image]

But the code is ugly:

```
k = linspace(0,  3*pi, 100);   

hbar = 1;
m = 1;
E =  ( (hbar^2) .* (k.^2) ) ./  (2*m);

E(33:66) = E(33:66) + 3;
E(66:100) = E(66:100) + 6;

E(33) = E(32);
E(66) = E(65);

E(34) = NaN;
E(67) = NaN;

hold on
plot(k,  E, [pi pi], [0 60], '--k', [2*pi 2*pi], [0 60], '--k');
plot(k(34), E(33), 'ob', 'MarkerFaceColor','b',...
        k(67), E(66), 'ob',  'MarkerFaceColor', 'b',...
        k(34), E(35), 'ob', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'b',...
        k(67), E(68), 'ob' , 'MarkerFaceColor', 'b');
hold off

xlabel('k')
ylabel('E(k)')
legend('E = hbar^2 k^2 / 2m', 'x = pi', 'x = 2pi')
title('Dispersion relation for periodic potential in extended zone.')

txt = '<- Band Gap';
text(k(35), E(33) +2, txt)
```

---